# Application Platform Specification

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ipod

I am designing an app for iphone & ipod the client wants the Some of the UI Specification for iphone and ipod to be different so i decided to create different XIB Files for iphone and ipod  as in universal apps for iphone and ipod but the problem is that i am not able differentiate between iphone and ipod on run time is there any way to check platform on runtime so as to load different Nib Files on runtime 
If there is any code or tutorial please guide me to the link
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was already asked several times .)

```
NSString *dtype = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if([dtype isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
{
   // iphone 
}
```

Possible examples of model strings are @”iPhone” and @”iPod touch”

Comment: well the code works.. it's just an other model string. that makes sense because the simulator is not an iphone.

Comment: right but if you're switching the iPhone "behaviors" just based on the isEqual strict check above, the proper behaviors won't apply when you run it under the simulator.  Probably better to do a starts with check ...

Answer (score 1):

[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] looks like the right source for this Information. You can check it if it contains iPod Touch or iPhone or.....

Answer (score 1):

Check the model property of UIDevice class

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

However, if you switch on that string, be aware that the simulator shows up as a separate device.

This:

```
NSString* model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
NSLog(@"model: %@", model);
```

Outputs:

```
2011-10-25 08:44:30.794 Craplet[921:b303] model: iPhone Simulator
```